# map in dataframe - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Here I'm passing a dataframe (CV_data) to add lable points for Descision Tree

```
def labelData(data):
    # label: row[end], features: row[0:end-1]
    return data.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[-1], row[:-1]))

m = labelData(CV_data)
```

Its giving me error

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Help needed

Comment: please go through http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/util.html